# With Colors.jl, how to change `Color`'s alpha transparency value?

Tags: colors, julia

If I have a Colors.jl `Color`, such as `HSLA(200,0.9,0.8,0.8)`, `HSL(200,0.9,0.8,0.8)`, or `RGB(200,100,100)`, is there a generic way to return a version of the color with a specified alpha transparency value (and promote the type if the input doesn't have an alpha value)?

E.g. something like `set_alpha(in_color,alpha=0.9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `alphacolor()` in the `Colors` package:

```
julia> using Colors

julia> c = RGBA(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
RGBA{Float64}(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0)

julia> alphacolor(c, 0.3)
ARGB{Float64}(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3)

julia> d = RGB(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
RGB{Float64}(0.5,0.5,0.5)

julia> alphacolor(d, 0.3)
ARGB{Float64}(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3)
```

This is the `set_alpha` function the OP wants. I learned this solution in

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/override-or-change-opacity-of-a-given-rgba-color/106880

Answer (score 3):

You can use the color in its non-alpha version in a constructor for the one with an alpha:

```
julia> a = HSL(200.0, 0.8, 0.8)
HSL{Float64}(200.0,0.8,0.8)

julia> aa = HSLA(a, 0.5)
HSLA{Float64}(200.0,0.8,0.8,0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Colors are defined as immutable structs for efficiency. Thus changing a field requires creating a new immutable. Turns out someone (Jan Weidner) wrote a package to do just that, `Accessors.jl`. So with this package it is possible to write:

```
julia> using Colors, Accessors

julia> c = HSLA(100,0.1,0.1,0.8)
HSLA{Float64}(100.0,0.1,0.1,0.8)

julia> @set c.alpha = 0.3
HSLA{Float64}(100.0,0.1,0.1,0.3)
```

Looks quite simple. Perhaps a package which defines more readable functions for these manipulations would be nice, but my googling attempts haven't found it.

Another option, inspired by @Bill's answer is

```
HSLA(HSL(c),0.2)
```

which does the same (inner `HSL` projects and `HSLA` adds back a transaparancy value)